# Assign a Jquery event to a varaible and not assign to a varaible?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between both code if the result is the same?

```js
$(function () {
    var registerUserCheckBox = $('#AcceptUserAgreement').click(
        onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick
    );
});
```

and

```js
$(function () {
    $('#AcceptUserAgreement').click(
        onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.click` will return the jQuery object that the `.click` was called on. If you'd like to use the jQuery object later, you can assign it to a variable:

```js
$(function () {
    const onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick = () => null;
    var registerUserCheckBox = $('#AcceptUserAgreement').click(
        onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick
    );
    registerUserCheckBox.css({ color: 'green' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AcceptUserAgreement">accept</div>
```

If you don't need to use that jQuery object later, then there's no point.

The code samples in your question are identical because `registerUserCheckBox` doesn't get used again, and can't be referenced once the function ends.

For my example above, there's no need to save the jQuery object in a variable in order to call `.css`, because you can just call `.css` on the result of `.click`:

```js
$(function () {
    const onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick = () => null;
    $('#AcceptUserAgreement')
      .click(
          onToggleRegisterUserDisabledClick
      )
      .css({ color: 'green' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="AcceptUserAgreement">accept</div>
```